# How to check if a PDF file is in RGB or CMYK?

Tags: print-design, pdf, cmyk, print-production, rgb

I have sent a PDF file to a printing company and they came back telling me that it is in RGB but should be in CMYK. It is strange as I really tried to make everything in CMYK (working with Adobe InDesign) and also run it through [www.pdf2cmyk.com](http://www.pdf2cmyk.com)

Is there a way to check for sure if a PDF is in CMYK or RGB?

I am looking for a method which is not based on visual examination since then I believe something can be missed. I would like to have a method saying yes or no (yes, only CMYK colors were used). Is this possible? What method do you think the printing company is using?

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but if you have InDesign there shouldn't be a need for converting using some website. It seems risky to do. You can control everything from InDesign yourself.

Comment: Agree. Do not use a website. The main risk would be transforming, for example, black text to a CMYK black text. This would be a total mess. The process MUST be done correctly from start.

Comment: Using a website is the reason you have RGB. Indesign would change any RGB file to desired CMYK profile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Wolff's answer is great and can be very useful.

Another way if you prefer to have the *data* determined without visually needing to verify anything is to use **Preflight** in Acrobat.

I'm using Acrobat Pro X here, merely because I prefer that version. Things should be very similar in newer versions of Acrobat.

With a PDF open, choose `View > Tools > Print Production > Preflight` from the menu.

You can use any of the options in the green box below to simply verify compliance with PDFX standards, which *requires* no RGB data to be compliant.

[image]

Once you run the compliance test, you can see easily *if* there is any RGB data and on what page of the PDF it is located. Below shows a non-compliant PDF containing RGB data on the left and a compliant PDF on the right.

[image]

---

If you *don't have* Acrobat Pro and are creating PDFs destined for commercial printing, you **need** Acrobat Pro. Similar to needing InDesign to  create professional-level layouts, print production *often* needs Acrobat Pro for some professional-level tasks. This is one such use case.

---

Note: If you are using Adobe InDesign you **can** [preflight with InDesign](https://indesignskills.com/skills/preflight-indesign/). This can be helpful to determine issues before you ever get to the PDF. Be aware though, even if you preflight in InDesign, the PDF Job Options used when exporting to a PDF *can* alter things. It's really best to preflight *production PDFs* using Acrobat, as opposed to preflighting *layout* files using InDesign.
<sub>I have no affiliation with the link above. It is merely posted for additional information.</sub>

Comment: Great, this is what I was looking for, thanks! I used preflight with InDesign. However, the files the printing company claims are in RGB are not that according to preflight (checked that the checking works by checking a file containing RGB). Will try to ask the printing company if they can provide more info.

Answer (score 13):

A simple way is opening the PDF in Adobe Acrobat and checking out *Overprint Preview*.

The button looks like this:

[image]

It opens this window:

[image]

Under *Show* you can filter which color mode you want to see. Set it to CMYK to see all CMYK objects in your document and to RGB to see all RGB objects (white objects can be hard to spot this way).

[image]

(Whether or not it's the *right* CMYK profile is another story.)

Comment: I really appreciate your response and detailed instructions. However, to my understanding you need Adobe Acrobat Pro for this, is that right?
Also, I am looking for a method which is not based on visual examination since then I believe something can be missed. I would like to have a method saying yes or no (yes, only CMYK colors were used). Is this possible? What method do you think the printing company is using?

Comment: @Bart printing companies use Acrobat and costly prepress software not for consumers.